# Grep nload command

Tags: grep

Hello I am trying to use grep alongisde with nload command to just get the current transfer speed:

```
nload | grep Curr:
```

But if I try this command I got only empty output and I have to quit with Control+C, any suggestions what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently nload is an interactive-only program and do not offer a batch mode, but its man states that the program uses /sys/class/net/ FS.
You can write a script to monitor RX or TX bandwidth by doing the same:

To monitor eth0 current download speed:

```
 cd /sys/class/net/eth0/statistics

 old="$(<rx_bytes)"; while $(sleep 1); do
 now=$(<rx_bytes); echo $((($now-$old)/1024)) KB/s; old=$now; done
```

If needed change eth0 with the name of your interface.
Replace `rx_bytes` with `tx_bytes` to monitor upload speed.

Answer (score 0):

this is also a 1 liner that displays Mbps instead of KiloBytes.

```
old="$(</sys/class/net/eth0/statistics/tx_bytes)"; while $(sleep 1); do 
now=$(</sys/class/net/eth0/statistics/tx_bytes); echo $((($now-$old)/131072)) 
Mb/s; old=$now; done
```